# $scope and setPristine() not working inside factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write convert my current api call into a factory which is reusable inside `ApiService` factory. However, I can't seem to clear the form.

So, what i can i do to make the clearForm function work as it is.

```
<form name="formName">
    <input type="name" ng-model="form.username"></input>
    <input type="password" ng=model="form.password"></input>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
<form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

form is in `$scope`. You can't access it without using `$scope` and factory don't have `$scope`.

try like this

```
$scope.formName.$setPristine();
```

All you can do is to pass that form to service and clear it

```
'clearForm': function(formName) {
            formName.$setPristine();
            formName.$setUntouched();
        }
```

from controller

```
FormFactory.clearForm($scope.formName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i cant access `$scope` directly inside the ApiService factory where I need to call FormFactory.clearForm

Comment: You can't access $scope from factory but you pass $scope to factory from controller @vincentsty

Comment: I pass the scope like this `ApiService.Login($scope)`  and i am able to access `scope.form` but not `scope.formName`, and thus $setPristine() still unedefined when i pass scope into `FormFactory.clearForm(scope.formName)`

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?